# Locking forms in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, thread-safety

I'm developing a Spring MVC Application, I've done the basic crud functionality, but I want my `update` operation to be thread safe, so one and only one person can edit the object.
So I've done a mechanical approach, which relies on creating an attribute `inUse`, so whenever a user wants to edit the object, the `inUse` attribute is set to `1`,so no other user can edit this object. Clearly it's not the best thing to do, because I can't know if the resource is free or not after editing ! ( For example if the user click on edit then close the page, the object will be locked indeterminably )

Can I solve this issue using Spring Batch ? is there any better approach to do this using Spring MVC ? Thanks.

Comment: To keep things simple you can use @Version field in domain layer: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Version.html

Comment: I see that the @Version annotation allow to prevent concurrent transaction commit to a field... But in my case I don't want to let the user access The Form ( Actually the form is long, it's a bad Idea to let the user fill the fields, and only when he wants to apply the changes he got the exception ! I want to avoid that )

Comment: I could suggest use the Transactional's isolation attributes too. Check the Reference documentation, **Serializable** is the most complete but has a little cost of performance. In that way you can avoid declare and use the **inUse** variable/field

Comment: This problem has nothing to do with SB and SB is not created to solve this kind or problem. Edit question and retag it

Answer (score 0):

If your CRUD operations are transactions, the updates will be safely serialized, and only one POST to a resource will be processed at once. You will not need to do any control of multithreading yourself.

Servlets process each request (including form POST requests) separately, in a separate thread, so actions by different users do not affect each other at all. The only shared state is what your application *makes* shared. In most cases only the database is shared, so there is no problem.